# MarkLogic - admin level restrict collections

Tags: marklogic

We know MarkLogic 9 admin can see all collections. However we want restrict two collections to junior admin. Only senior admin can see restrict collections.

junior admin can do all tasks same as Senior admin on ports 8001/8000 but not allow to view restrict collections. is that possible?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how to ensure that documents in these restricted collections cannot be read by the junior admins, or that the existence of the restricted collections and their names are not visible?

Comment: Want to ensure that documents in these restricted collections cannot be read by the junior admins. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MarkLogic Server security model has a set of tools you can use to control access to documents. These authorization tools control creating, inserting into, updating, and reading documents in a database.

What you're looking for is assigning different roles to these admins and persisting documents that will get one or the other role, depending on who has to get access to them.

## Document Permissions

Permissions set on a document define access to capabilities (read, insert, update, node-update, and execute) for that document. Each permission consists of a capability and a role. This section describes how to set permissions on a document. It includes the following subsections:

[Capabilities Associated Through Permission](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/permissions#id_62440)

[Setting Document Permissions](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/permissions#id_12138)